# Bigquery - UNION ALL same query with different parameters

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a very large query and I want to UNION ALL the same query but changing two different parameters. Thus, to make the query more readable I want to avoid using UNION ALL. Here a **short example** (non-sense but it gives an idea)
of what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name,'7 days' FROM T WHERE DATE(event_time) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE())
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT Name, '14 DAYS' FROM T WHERE DATE(event_time) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE())
```

So the whole point is to avoid this union and make it scalable for more unions, just changing the intervals without creating hundreds of lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

You could write this as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, CONCAT(d, ' days')
FROM T JOIN
     (UNNEST(ARRAY[7, 14]) d
     ON DATE(event_time) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL d DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE())
```

This query is basically non-sense, given that it is just going to be repeating recent names for every time period.

But the key idea is to `UNNEST()` an array with the values you want and then use `JOIN` instead of `WHERE`.